# LWC Datatable Inline Edit for Picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

I have create an LWC datatable component to handle related record and Edit the records once displayed. I have one picklist field and i need to render as picklist during inline edit.

I have implemented LWC data Custom Type to handle picklist as its supported by datatable. But when i click inline edit the picklist options are not visible.

---Child Component Code---

```html
<template>
    <span class="slds-truncate"  title={value}>{value}</span>
</template-->
```

picklistColumn.html:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="picklist" data-inputable="true" label={typeAttributes.label} value={editedValue}
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} options={typeAttributes.options} variant='label-hidden'
        dropdown-alignment="auto">
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

datatablePicklist.html

```html
<template>

</template>
```

datatablePicklist.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import picklistColumn from './picklistColumn.html';
import  pickliststatic from './pickliststatic.html'

export default class datatablePicklist extends LightningDatatable {
  
    
    static customTypes = {
        picklistColumn: {
            template: pickliststatic,
            editTemplate: picklistColumn,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant','name']
        }
    };
}
```

Parent Component:
HTML

```html
<lightning-card key={table.id} title={table.name} variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:folder"
            class="cardSpinner">
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_small">
                <c-aptsdatatable-picklist key={table.id} key-field="Id" data={table.data} columns={table.columns}
                    onvalueselect={handleSelection} draft-values={table.draftValues} oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction} type-attributes={typeAttributes} onsave={handleSave}
                    oncancel={handleCancel} data-table-id={table.id}
                    hide-checkbox-column>
                </c-aptsdatatable-picklist>
</div>
</lightning-card>
```

Parent.JS
Data and Column value are coming for Apex

```js
connectedCallback() {
            loadStyle(this, modal);
            console.log('Id: ' + this.RecordId);

            getdata({ recordId: this.RecordId })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.tables = response.map((table) => ({
                            id: table.id,
                            tableId: table.id,
                            name: table.name,
                            data: table.dataList ? table.dataList.map((record) => ({
                                ...record,
                                deleteRow: 'Delete',
                                isNew: false,
                            })) : [],
                            columns: table.columns.map((column) => {
                                if (column.type === 'picklistColumn') {
                                    return {
                                        ...column,
                                        type: 'picklistColumn',
                                        
                                        typeAttributes: {
                                            editable: true,
                                            fieldName: column.fieldName,
                                            placeholder: 'Select an option',
                                            options: column.picklistOptions.map((option) => ({
                                                label: option,
                                                value: option,
                                            })),
                                        },
                                    };
                                } else {
                                    return {
                                        ...column,
                                        editable: true,
                                    };
                                }
                            }).concat({
                                label: 'Actions',
                                type: 'button',
                                typeAttributes: {
                                    label: 'Delete',
                                    name: 'delete',
                                    iconName: 'utility:delete',
                                    variant: 'destructive',
                                },
                                cellAttributes: {
                                    class: 'slds-cell-edit-delete-action',
                                },
                            }),
                            draftValues: [],
                        }));

                        // Set the tableId property
                        if (this.tables.length > 0) {
                            this.tableId = this.tables[0].id;
                        }
                        console.log('tables' + this.tables);
                        console.log('Agr' + JSON.stringify(this.tables));

                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error retrieving data', error);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
```

[image]
Any Idea what I am missing or issue?

Comment: Hi, Arun. Would you please paste a screenshot of how is it looking now?

Comment: Hello @sergio, i have attached the screenshots. When i click edit loading the combobox with only placeholder without any picklist values.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/117407/sergio-pedraza-j

Comment: Hey, have you checked https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/custom-types-in-lwc-lightning-datatable#4-use-custom-type-in-custom-lightning-datatable? I was trying to re-render your solution, but since the code is not complete, there's not much I can do to debug.

Comment: Hello @SergioPedrazaJ. i have pasted the example of the solution from my dev org where while adding a new row is  showing the same issue

Comment: Hello @SergioPedrazaJ. Please find the complete example of code https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404668/lwc-datatable-picklist-inline-edit